# $\forall x$ versus $\exists x$ in the definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta, quantifiers

Suppose $f: A \to \Bbb R$ and $x \in A$. Let $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L,$ that is,

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \quad \text{such that if} \quad x \in A, \quad \text{ and } |x - c| < \delta \to |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$$

Why is it "for all $x$" instead of "there exists an $x$"? If $f=x=8$ and $L=c=5,$ then the condition won't be satisfied since $|f - L| = 3 \not< 1 = \varepsilon$. However, writing "$\exists x$" is solving the problem, because then I can always find some $x$ that won't break the condition.

Comment: In the definition it is not "for all $x$" but "for all $x$ sufficiently close to $c$", formally: "there exist some $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $|x-c|<\delta$".E.g. in your example, $\delta=1$ (or any positive $\delta \le1$) does the job (and excludes $x=8$).

Comment: Your definition is wrong. You say "...if $x\in A$ and ..." but you should say "...if $x\in A$ then ...". These things matter.

Comment: On top of ancient mathematician's remark, could you re-read the 2nd sentence from the last to check whether it really makes sense to you?  It's better that you make some self-corrections first, otherwise it's hard to know which of your several fundamental misunderstandings to start addressing.

Comment: @AxiomFeraas, you forgot to write “$x\neq c$” in the definition of limit.

Comment: also, the constant function $f(x) = 8$ never will have limit equal to $L = 5$, as you just have shown. You seem to mix up a lot of the numbers occuring in the definition of limit of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your problem solved, we need to come back to the beginning.

What you have written up there, is called Epsilon ($\epsilon$)- Delta ($\delta$) proof of limit, which is a precise way to define limits. Before you have this kind of definition, you probably use this type of definition instead:

> Given a function $y = f(x)$, and an x-value, $c$, we have the limit of $f(x)$ as it approach $c$ is $L$ if one or more of these cases happen: $y$ tends to reach $L$ as $x$ tends to $c$; $y$ approaches $L$ as $x$ approaches $c$; $y$ is near $L$ whenever $x$ is near $c$.

When you define it as above, you realise, that it is not exact. In what way that those relations of "tends", "approach" or "near" the variable actually is? That is when you have the Epsilon-Delta proof. It is the result of formalizing the third statement:

> If $x$ is within the tolerance level of $c$, then the corresponding value $y = f(x)$ is within the tolerance level of $L$.

From here, you can see that, we are taking the approximation that is defined as "tends to" or "approach" to the tolerance level, the
degree of accuracy required in a measurement or the acceptable range of values in which the measurement will be acceptable in our calculation. Which is further reduced into notation by saying:

> If $x$ is within $\delta$ unit of $c$, then the corresponding value of $y$ is within $\epsilon$ units of $L$.

Mathematically, this is written as

$$|x-c| < \delta \longrightarrow |y - L| < \epsilon$$

with the LHS as $$c - \delta < x < c + \delta$$ and the RHS as $$L - \epsilon < y < L - \epsilon$$

Formally, we would have this definition of limit

> Definition: The limit of a function $f(x)$: Let $I$ be an open interval that $c,x \in I$,$x \neq c$, $f(x)$ is defined everywhere in $I$ except possibly at $c$. The function $f(x)$ is defined as $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. The limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches c is $L$, denoted by $$ \lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L $$ is such that $$\forall \: \epsilon > 0, \exists \: \delta \: s.t. \: |x-c| < \delta \longrightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon $$

From all of this, I think it is suffice for you to understand why it must be that way. Another remark is that, x is independent of y. And you are misunderstanding both misreading the definition.

Reference: [Epsilon-Delta definition of a limit](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_3e_(Apex)/01%3A_Limits/1.02%3A_Epsilon-Delta_Definition_of_a_Limit)

Comment: @87, you forgot to write “$x\neq c$” in the definition of limit.

Comment: It is fixed. Thanks for poiting it out!

Comment: @区なしま I think Angelo meant in the epsilon-delta line (`0<|x-c|<δ`).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, sorry for Saturday's verbosity and let's start:

The difference between the word "all" and the word "some" ("exists") is obvious: compare "all the money in the world is mine" and "some of the money in the world is mine". Maybe we would like the first, but we live in the second.

Thus, it is clear that you **significantly relax** the requirements if the  universal quantifier is replaced by the existential quantifier.

But let's look at the issue more broadly: quantifiers are designed to impose conditions on variables, but they are, let's say, too extreme - or all or at least one. Let's consider a generalization of the limit to the case when we impose a condition on a part of the set.

Let's assume $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$, where $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $c$ is limit point for $E$

Formally limit for function $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ with respect to $E$ is following (Vladimir A. Zorich - Mathematical Analysis I-Springer (2016), page 106 or [Limit_of_a_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function)) :

$$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)(\color{red}\forall x \in E)\Big(0<|x-c|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-A|<\varepsilon \Big)$$

Also we can write it as following

$$(\forall \varepsilon>0)(\exists \delta>0)\Big(\color{red}\forall x \in E\cap \{x:0<|x-c|<\delta\}\Big)\Big( |f(x)-A|<\varepsilon \Big)$$

By choosing a different $E$ we can control the extent to which the second universal quantifier (indicated in red) is applied.

Let's consider the well-known [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function)

$$D(x)=\begin{cases} 1,  & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
0, & x\notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

If we take $E= \mathbb{R}$, then limit doesn't exists, but it exists if $E= \mathbb{Q}$ or $E= \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Returning to your situation, **limit exists** also when $E= \mathbb{R}$ and we change red $\forall$ to $\exists$.

Comment: Zkutch, congratulation! Here you are the only person who did not forget to write “$x\neq c$” in the definition of limit. For this reason, I have just upvoted you.

Comment: Thanks @Angelo. Without it this will be definition of continuity, but it's sad if that's the only reason for your upvote. I was hoping I wrote something a bit helpful.

Comment: Zkutch, I completely agree with you. Do not be sad, your answer is very good and helpful. I like it very much!

Comment: (pardon for answering late, I had final exams and my mind was not clear). But your answer is extraordinary GREAT, especially with the last example, which showed why it is wrong to say ∃x. However, I am having little different issue with ∀x, but I think I ma figuring it out. I will come back if otherwise.